# How to add comments to a question in Askubuntu?

Tags: discussion

I do not know how to comments to a question please help. 
I am very new to Askubuntu and do not know how to do many things.

Comment: Yuo must to have this privilege: http://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment

Comment: You can always comment on your _own_ questions and answers. You gain the ability to comment on _other's_ posts after you've gained at least 50 reputation.

Answer (score 5):

You have to have 50 reputation points to be able to leave comments.  See the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq).

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to askubuntu.com

You need at least 50 reputation in order to comment.

When you have achieved this: to comment on a question,go to the bottom of the question, wou will find option with 'flag','edit' and 'share'. Below this links, there is line with 'add comment'. Click on this link and add your say about the desirable question.

About askubuntu- this is a site where the basic queries and problems associated with ubuntu are answered.

You can ask a question if you encounter a problem while installation,running,upgrading,updating or using ubuntu with a single click button available at the top right corner of the webpage below the menu bar.

Be sure to research well on the error you have received before asking since there may be others who many have encountered the same problem and have posted the question earlier.So,search for the question first.

Based on the questions asked, people who are sure will answer it. Some may even edit the question to make it better and make more sense.The answer may be voted along with the question.The answer accepted by the person who asks it is rated as the best answer.

The votes for your question or answer will get you points known as reputation and you will earn batches for it in order to encourage you yo continue your contribution and help make ubuntu a better operating system with no errors.